# Recursively locate and modify css of first element of particular type

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an html structure defined like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=photoItems>
    <div class=photoWrapper>
      <img class="image" ... />
    </div>
    <div class=photoWrapper>
      <img class="image" ... />
    </div>
    <div class=photoWrapper>
      <img class="image" ... />
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is use the "container" style to recursively go through its children and locate the first instance of type `<img/>` and force a `display:none;`. Kind of like this (non-working css):

```
.container {
  width: 100%;

  > img:first-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

From what I understand the 'first-of-type' selector only works at the sibling level, however for reasons I am only able to operate at the "container" level - so is there a way to recursively select the first instance of an image from the styling at the great-grandfather level?

Comment: the question that immediately pops into my head from your example, is it *always* assumed that there will be an image tag in that exact position? Meaning, why would it matter if it was there or not, no reason to 'search' for it; if its there the rule gets applied, if its not the rule doesn't. For example: `.container .photoWrapper:first-of-type > img {}`

Comment: *"so is there a way to recursively select the first instance of an image from the styling at the great-grandfather level?"* - No, there isn't. As mentioned in an answer below, JS is your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my own understanding, ">" selector selects the elements that is first descendant of an element. Like for example `div > img`, this one selects all the `img` that are first descendant of the div and not the `img` that is on its second successor.

So, if I didn't misunderstood your question, what you are trying to accomplish is to find the very first `img` inside the `.container` class by using the `:first-of-type` selector. If we base on the structure of your elements, it will never happen. This is because you are using ">" selector but there are no direct descendants of `img` inside since images are being wrapped inside `.photoWrapper` class. And if you use `div img:first-of-type`, this will select all the first instance of image inside the `div` as well as in its successors.

Sadly, I think there's still no feature/selector on CSS that can find elements to all its successor in accordance to your question. You can read about selectors here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp / 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Hmm I don't know if you prefer this, but here's my workaround for your question. I will use `find('img:first')` function of jquery.

Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.container').find('img:first').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class=photoItems>
    <div class=photoWrapper>
      <img class="image" alt="1" />
    </div>
    <div class=photoWrapper>
      <img class="image" alt="2"  />
    </div>
    <div class=photoWrapper>
      <img class="image" alt="3"  />
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
.container .photoWrapper:first-child img {
  display:none;
}
```